# Title: ADB error and Android Emulator stuck at logo after wiping data

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I'm encountering an issue with my Android emulator. After wiping out the data, the emulator gets stuck at the logo screen and shows no progress. When I try to connect to the emulator using ADB, I get an error message indicating that the device is offline or unauthorized. I have tried restarting the emulator and my computer, but the problem persists. What can I do to resolve this issue and get my emulator working again?

I tried to wipe out data as told by many experts on Internet. But things are same for me after doing that.